# Inline method with asm bytecode manipulator

Tags: java, inline, java-bytecode-asm

I'm trying to make an inline optimization and I'm using this paper as reference http://modularity.info/conference/2007/program/industry/I5-UsingASMFramework.pdf (3.2.6). I'm using ASM 7 and some of the code is deprecated so if you can point me to a newer article I would be grateteful.

Regardless of the version, I still don't get exactly how this works

```
public static class InliningAdapter extends RemappingMethodAdapter
{ 
    private final LocalVariablesSorter lvs; 
    private final Label end; 
    public InliningAdapter(LocalVariablesSorter mv, Label end, int acc, String desc, Remapper remapper) { 
        super(acc, desc, mv, remapper); 
        this.lvs = mv; 
        this.end = end; 
        // guess it's offset as it is written that way below
        int off = (acc & Opcodes.ACC_STATIC)!=0 ? 0 : 1; 
        Type[] args = Type.getArgumentTypes(desc); 
        for (int i = args.length-1; i >= 0; i--) { 
            super.visitVarInsn(args[i].getOpcode(Opcodes.ISTORE), i + offset); 
        } 
        if(offset>0) { 
            super.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ASTORE, 0); 
        } 
    } 
    public void visitInsn(int opcode) { 
        if(opcode==Opcodes.RETURN) { 
            super.visitJumpInsn(Opcodes.GOTO, end); 
        } else { 
            super.visitInsn(opcode); 
        } 
    } 
    public void visitMaxs(int stack, int locals) {   } 

    protected int newLocalMapping(Type type) { 
        return lvs.newLocal(type); 
    } 
}
```

I get that since we inline, the parameters that were loaded in the stack and ready to be used by a method invocation must now be stored back in local remapped variables. However in the for loop that stores these parameters the index used (i + offset) can very well be 0,1 e.t.c and hence by the LocalVariableSorter's remap method this values might not be remapped because they might be considered method parameters.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29802059/remapper-variables-during-bytecode-method-inlining-by-asm) thread it states that the super command in the cosntructor "super(acc, desc, mv, remapper);" must be changed to super(acc | Opcodes.ACC_STATIC, "()V", mv, remapper); in order to remap every variable including those with index smaller than the number of the parameters. Is the author of the paper wrong? is this change necessary?

Comment: Why are you trying to inline a method in bytecode?  The JVM JIT does this at runtime.

Comment: I have a tool that does static analysis. I'm trying to implement the results of such an analysis to the analyzed programs.

Comment: Well, you have the linked thread, you have your own understanding, so what doubt is actually left? By the way, looking at this code, I’m wondering whether it works correctly with `long` or `double` parameters…